# What is the default opacity of the background of the iOS AlertController?

Tags: ios, mobile, uialertcontroller, ios12

E.g. of the gray around this alert:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the iOS Debug View Hierarchy to analyze each view:

[image: debug view hierarchy output]

In the sidebar, we can see that the background has an alpha of 0.4 and an RGB of (0, 0, 0).

[image: sidebar info]